# Existence of a free subgroup of an amalgamated product

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Suppose $G$ = $ A*_{C}B$, where $|A:C|$ $\geq$ $3$ and $|B:C|$ $\geq$ $2$. How might I show that $G$ has a free subgroup of rank $2$? Here I am not assuming $C$ to be finitely generated.

For me, a reduced word of the amalgam is of the form $(h, s_1, ..., s_n)$ where $h \in C$, and the $s_i$s alternate between $A_1$ and $B_1$ where these are right coset representatives of $C$ in $A$, $B$ respectively and are both assumed to contain $1$ and we have $s_i \ne1$ for all $i$. A cyclically reduced word is such that also $(s_1, s_n)$ is reduced. So if the indexes are as above, there exist distinct cyclically reduced words, and cyclically reduced words have infinite order..

I also know that if $F$ is a subgroup of the amalgam that intersects trivially any conjugate of $A$ or $B$ then $F$ must be free, but I'm not sure how I would apply this.

Hints as to how to proceed with this question (or for more general questions of the same form) would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Second attempt: let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be in distinct nontrivial cosets of $C$ in $A$, and $b \in B \setminus C$. Then the two commutators $[a_1,c]=a_1^{-1}c^{-1}a_1c$ and $[a_2,c]$ generate a free subgroup of rank $2$. That's basicaIly because the only cancellation possible in products is $[a_1,c][a_2,c]^{-1} = a_1^{-1}c^{-1}a_1a_2^{-1}ca_2$. I'll leave you to fill in the details.

Comment: @DerekHolt, what is c here? is that meant to be b?

Comment: Yes, sorry, $c=b$.